# cakephp - code for multiple file upload using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakePHP. Can someone please help me with the code for a multiple file upload using HTML 5 using cake php. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>Size</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach($files as $file): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $file['Doc']['id'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($file['Doc']['name'], array('controller' => 'files', 'action' => 'uploads', $file['Doc']['name'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo number_format($file['Doc']['size']/1023,0).' KB';?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>

<h1>Add a File</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Doc',array('type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->file('File');
    echo $this->Form->submit('Upload');
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

Comment: Please read the "faq" section (link at top right) before posting a question, as this does not meet the requirements for a question accepted at StackOverflow.  Thanks :)

Comment: I did read it, not sure what when wrong, I will try again

Comment: @Ann - I have added your code into the question body. Maybe delete your comment/reply now, since it's a bit of a mess :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you OK with using an existing plugin for this? If so, do you want to try this plugin: https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload/ - supports multi-file upload, AJAX, etc.

Comment: Ah most likely not - its for CakePHP 2.x.

Comment: I downloaded and followed all the instructions in the readme file. I am still not sure of how to use it. It lets me select only one file in the file dialog box, I have tried it in google chrome and IE.

Comment: I tried to drag from file dialog box to the browser, it lets me do only one file upload. I am using google chrome. Thanks for your help so far